Can arpeggios have stacked notes in them?
For example are these arpeggios:


The second measure, with both arpeggiation and repeating pitches, is a bit odd/unidiomatic.

Once again, please give the rest of the world an opportunity to answer, before choosing - it's not even awake yet!

Yes, arpeggios can include chords. One example comes from Chopin's second Ballade. The second portion of the piece opens with a furious downward arpeggio that features some two-note chords. Below are measures 46–48. The right hand in measures 46 and 48 clearly contain arpeggios, but, since arpeggios are usually considered one-directional, it's debatable whether or not to call m. 47 an arpeggio. But the phrase "series of arpeggiated chords" would be understood by sufficiently experienced pianists.
The left hand in mm. 46 and 48 could be called "arpeggiated octaves".


Might be worth clarifying, that's "yes" to the general premise in the title, not necessarily to "are these arpeggios," of the OP's specific examples.

Arpeggio comes from the Italian 'arpeggiare' - to play on a harp. They are essentially broken chords, and as such, will have the particular chord notes played sequentially, up or down. that then precludes playing two or more notes simultaneously.
That brings us to the thorny question - do just two notes constitute a chord? We're split down the middle on that one, but with an arpeggio, there will be many more than two notes in any case, producing the triad or octave copies of it one note at a time.
So, your 1st example could be called an arpeggio, whereas the 2nd will simply be 'chords'. That couldn't be an arpeggio anyway, as the direction of pitch keeps changing!
Notes written as chords can also be arpeggiated - they look like stacked notes, but will have a squiggly line in front of them, sometimes with an arrowhead showing the direction in which to be played, otherwise bottom to top is normal. In fact, your 1st example really only qualifies regarding the final three notes; not really a good example, from the definition above.

That depends on the definition. Strictly speaking maybe no. An arpeggio is a chord that is broken in ascending or descending order. A broken chord is a chord where the pitches do not fall simultaneously. This might or might not imply that no two pitches must fall on the same time.
Of course in practice it is not uncommon for arpeggiated chords not to be placed fully equal, and also for some notes occasionally falling on the same time.
Now for the elephant in the room: As Tim has stated your examples to not actually follow the definition of an arpeggiated chord. Rather you have arbitrary homophonic movements around a chord laced with some chords. This can of course be done and is rather common in piano music, both in a polyphonic way (the chords give one voice and the continuous eighth notes give another voice) as well as in a totally arbitrary way. But you should not consider this as arpeggiation.
